# how to set shadow for round image(css)

Tags: html, css

I'm new to shadow in css can we set shadows for
 round image(i mean to a circle image).

if it is possible, please give me a code for this in css.
   thanks in advance

Comment: Add `border-radius: 100%;` to the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS3 box shadows apply shadows to the element, not the content of the element. In other words if you have an image (which is rectangular) but the image itself is of a circle, the shadow will be applied to the rectangular image element, not the actual subject of the image.

**UPDATE**:

Of course, you can always use the canvas element to play with shadows. Here's a **[jsFiddle  example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yX4tG/)** of both drawing a circle and loading a circle, then applying a shadow effect to both.

Answer (score 17):

This is impossible since CSS does not know the shape of the image contents (e.g. interpret transparency).
You could make a circle with CSS3 and give a shadow, [see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjMbh/1).

```
div {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: not so true, images can be rounded as well using the same technique, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/MQrqh/)

Comment: You're right, edited my answer to clarify what I actually meant.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just add a border-radius: 50% to your image along with the box shadow property :) works in my img tag.

Answer (score 5):

shadows are independent of shapes in css, you can use the shadow property for circle after creating circle.
You can use the following code for that, it should work fine

```
.circle{ 
   width:150px;height:150px;
   border: solid 1px #555;
   background-color: #eed;
   box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
   -o-box-shadow: 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   border-radius:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is great tutorial for box-shadowing with examples [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

Also, simple css3 for rounding corners in cross browser

```
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

just adjust the pix to the corner roundness you want, or use `em`s instead

Answer (score 2):

This thing worked for me. I wanted a rounded shadow around the image 32x32.

```
<a class="media-links" href="">
   <img class="media-imgs" src="">
</a>
```

CSS is like this.

```
        img.media-imgs
        {
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        }

        img.media-imgs:hover
        {
                -webkit-animation-name: greenPulse;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px #91bd09;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
box-shadow: 0 0 98px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); // this is must but values are just an example, set accordingly.
border-radius: 50%; //this is must.
```

Apply this CSS to your  tag or its class, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy! Set `border-radius: 50%;` on your image element.

It rounds your image tag and it's drop-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not allow you to add shadows to shapes INSIDE images. CSS has no clue what the image looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in css3 doing exactly what you whant. But, of course, this is not yet implemented by all browsers (IE...)
Have a look there : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: ie9 supports box-shadow, but for previous ie versions you'll need a js conversion function of somesort

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way i can get is to put the image in a **div** and then provide the border radius same as image to that div and apply **box-shadow** to that **div**

```
.topDiv{
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
.img{
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

**this will do the work.**