# Unable to do same effect for five canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I followed the code which is given by j08691 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808253/how-to-set-shadow-for-round-imagecss) for canvas.

It worked perfectly and i tried for five canvas elements, but getting error in JavaScript since I'm beginner in JavaScript please help me.

```
var icon =new Array("icon1","icon2","icon3","icon4","icon5");
var c = new Array();
var ctx = new Array(5);
var img = new Array(5);
var imgsrc = new Array("imgsrc1","imgsrc2","imgsrc3","imgsrc4","imgsrc5");

$(document).ready(function()
{

var i=0;

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
{
c[i]=document.getElementById(icon[i]);
ctx[i]=c[i].getContext("2d");
ctx[i].shadowOffsetX = 12;
ctx[i].shadowOffsetY = 4;
ctx[i].shadowBlur = 5;
ctx[i].shadowColor = '#666';
img[i] = new Image();
img[i].onload = function(i){
ctx[i].drawImage(img[i], 0, 0); //getting error here as "ctx[i] undefined"
};
img[i].src =imgsrc[i];
}

});
```

HTML

```
   <canvas id="icon1" width="185" height="130" >
   <canvas id="icon2" width="185" height="130" >
   <canvas id="icon3" width="185" height="130" >
   <canvas id="icon4" width="185" height="130" >
   <canvas id="icon5" width="185" height="130" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanations of @Nickolay and @apsillers are both correct, but their code(s) do(es)n't work because they redefine an `i`/`ctxi` argument, which is never assigned. Use the following instead:

```
function getHandler(i) {
    return function() {
        ctx[i].drawImage(img[i], 0, 0);
    };
}
img[i].onload = getHandler(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ctx[i] and img[i] are out of scope in the onload handler.

img[[i] however is accessible through this but you should pass ctx[i] as an argument of your onload handler

```
        img[i].onload = function(ctxi) {
            return function(ctxi) {
                ctxi.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            }
        }(ctx[i]);
```