# How to add shadow to rounded corners

Tags: css

I am trying to add shadow to circle by using

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 10px black;
```

, but it comes up with square border .
How can i add the shadow to circle.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 10px black;
    
}

.circle:after {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1E73BE;
  content: "";
}

.circle__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__content {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<div class="circle__inner">
<div class="circle__wrapper">
<div class="circle__content">This is responsive circle</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set shadow for round image(css)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808253/how-to-set-shadow-for-round-imagecss)

Comment: In your css, if you use border-radius to .circle then you'll get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add `border-radius: 50%;` to the `.circle`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff74c8d5/2/)

CSS

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 10px black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `border-radius` this class `.circle`

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 10px black;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
    
}

.circle:after {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1E73BE;
  content: "";
}

.circle__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__content {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<div class="circle__inner">
<div class="circle__wrapper">
<div class="circle__content">This is responsive circle</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to change approach and use `position: absolute;` for `.circle__content:after` pseudo-element. The final code is the following:

```
.circle__content:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```